# scala regex : extract file extension

Tags: regex, scala, match, case, file-extension

```
val file_name="D:/folder1/folder2/filename.ext"    //filename
val reg_ex = """(.*?).(\\\\w*$)""".r  //regex pattern

 file_name match {
      case reg_ex(one , two) =>s"$two is extension"
      case _ => println(" file_reg_ex none")
    }
```

I want to extract file extension i.e."ext" from the above using scala regex , using match & case.

I am using above regex and it is going into not match case.

Any pointers to regex tutorials will be helpful.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Post some code that doesn't work and we can point out where it's going off track.

Comment: @jwvh I have updated the code , please check

Answer (score 8):

A few minor adjustments.

```
val reg_ex = """.*\.(\w+)""".r

file_name match {
  case reg_ex(ext) =>s"$ext is extension"
  case _ => println("file_reg_ex none"); ""
}
```

Only one capture group needed. Ignore everything before the final dot, `\.` (escaped so it's a dot and not an "any char") and capture the rest.

The default, `case _`, should do more than `println`. It should return the same type as the match.

Comment: that worked !! THanks a lot , can you point me to any regex tutorials, probably specific to scala will be much more better , that will be great.

Comment: 1 - Glad I could help. 2 - The proper expression of gratitude, here on SO, is an up-vote and/or mark the answer as "accepted". 3 - I'm sure there are many fine regex tutorials on-line. I haven't used any recently so I don't have any recommendations.

Comment: +1 to fixing the `case _` in the answer. Scala regex is java regex, but there are examples at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/matching/Regex.html For parsing file paths, you really want a lib, not regexes. There are several libs.